# Find consecutive zeros in Python, based on time

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have a pandas `df1` with a `datetime` column and a `count` column. If there is a string of 0s for a consecutive hour, and less than 2 minutes of data > 0 within that hour (a 'spike tolerance'), it is considered invalid.

The `datetime` is in 5 second intervals but not always consistent (i.e. can jump from 6:00:00 to 14:00:00, skipping all the time in between) so the difference between rows should be 5 seconds in order to be considered a consecutive period of time.

I would like to add a new column `flag` that marks a 0 for invalid and a 1 for valid.

Sample data

```
  time        count        flag
00:00:05      0           0
00:00:10      0           0
.....         all 0       0
01:00:05      0           0
01:00:10      33          1
01:00:15      19          1
.......       n>0         1
02:00:10      12          1
```

Comment: Can you add sample of data and desired output?

Comment: Are the hours fixed (i.e. 1-2, 2-3) or is it a rolling 'last 60 minutes' calculation?

Comment: Does that edit help at all? I tried to make it clear, but not too easy. It would be a rolling calculation, does that make things even trickier?

Answer (score 0):

transposed and turn it into a series:

```
y = df.T.unstack()
```

Then to make up for lack of contiguous groupby in pandas:

```
y * (y.groupby((y != y.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1)

OUT: 0     0
1     0
2     1
3     2
4     3
5     0
6     0
7     1
8     0
9     1
10    2
```

This will yield the number of consecutive values

Comment: `y * (y.groupby((y != y.shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() + 1)` Apply that onto your series tell me if it worked